# How can I remove the default application indicators, like the power or the volume indicator, in Unity?

Tags: unity, indicator, uninstall, delete

After installing a bunch of new application indicators, I realized that I was using a lot of the top-bar space, and wanted to get rid of some default indicators to have more space. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can uninstall the individual indicator packages entirely using `Synaptic Package Manager`, or blacklist the indicator icons using `Gconf-editor`.

For example, I've removed the `indicator-me` package that shows username and chat status.

The volume indicator is called `indicator-sound`, and the indicator with your username and session management is called `indicator-session`. The battery indicator is configurable in the power management settings.

Search for 'indicator' in Synaptic to see more of them.